User Left Channel
Hellow, I want to ask. How to get notification when someone is left my channel? I've tried using @client.on(events.ChatAction(chats=IDChannel)) but still nothing happens.
I've tried using @client.on(events.ChatAction(chats=IDChannel)) but nothing happens. My expectation is that after someone leaves my channel, I get a notification that someone has left the channel.
